# How can I access my Windows based home network from my Mac?

Tags: windows, mac, osx-snow-leopard, home-networking

I have put a few files on my shared drive on my Windows XP home network. How do I access them through my Mac? I just want to copy them over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to the Finder
2. Hit Cmd-K (or "Go" menu, then "Connect to Server..."
3. In the "Server address" box, type "smb://*host or IP*/*share name*", e.g. smb://192.168.0.5/music

Depending on how your shared drive is configured, you may be prompted to enter username and password.

Your shared drive will now appear as a drive on your mac.